# Pulling cookie value with jQuery for MailChimp popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, popup, mailchimp

I'm trying to read a cookie, but don't have a clue how, basically.

The cookies are being set OK, but don't seem to be read properly.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
mce_jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    mce_jQuery('#mc_embed_signup').hide();
    cks = document.cookie.split( ';' );
    var show=true;
    for(i=0;i<cks.length;i++){
        parts = cks[i].split('=');
        if( parts[0].indexOf('MCEvilPopupClosed')>0 ) show = false;
    }
```

It then runs on to do the following, but I'd like to simplify the above and not worry about the expiry date - only do the if(show=true) bit below when:

IF MCEvilPopupClosed value = yes...

```
    if (show=true){
        mce_jQuery('#mc_embed_signup a.mc_embed_close').show();
        setTimeout( function(){ mce_jQuery('#mc_embed_signup').fadeIn();} , 1000);
        mce_jQuery('#mc_embed_signup a.mc_embed_close').click(function(){ mcEvilPopupClose();});
    }
});
```

Not really sure how to go about doing this?

Comment: What's mce_jQuery? A noConflict?

Comment: I think so, yes.  It's code from MailChimp, so I assume that's their noConflict prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js

```
var mycookie = $.cookie('the_cookie')
```